# Filter table by letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I want to sort a table with one column by beginning letter. So if I click e.g.
button 'e' the page should only show entries beginning with an 'e'.

Comment: That's not sorting though, that's filtering...

Comment: can you show how you are populating your table? It is from a request, an array... Try to provide more information.

Comment: You have to tell us about the data structure used to build the table or ppl cant help you.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: also a table with 1 column is an array and not much of a table. then just array.filter((cell) => cell.startsWith("e"));

Comment: I have a simple html table echoed from a sql database.

So someting like
`<tr><td>afoo</td></tr>
<tr><td>cfoo</td></tr>`

Comment: Try out the [filter widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an array with your data, you can use [javascript filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Something like:

```
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const result = words.filter(word => word.charAt(0) == 'e');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a filter,

You can store the value of those buttons

Ej. var filterValue = 'e'

And if you got an array of values, you can use the filter method.

var filteredArray = array.filter(a => a.startsWith(filterValue)).

And display that filtered array